# ¿Como pasar un array tipo int a una pila en java?

Tags: java, array, pilas, stack

Generalmente lo que necesito es intercambiar el orden de los elementos de mi array tipo int, es decir cambiar la posición al revés, como por ejemplo: {1,2,3} a {3,2,1}

Estoy pensando en implementar una pila que reciba los elementos de ese array, y luego desapilarla en otro array, pero no tengo idea de como hacerlo, me podrían ayudar por favor?

```
  public void VectorInvertido(View view){
  
       int Isignal1[] = {1,2,2,1,0};
       //pasar array a pila


}
```

Comment: Saludos. Desde el buscador web de tu prefencia `java reverse array`; con ello encontrarás como hacerlo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La forma más simple es:

```
List<Integer> lista = Arrays.asList(array);
Collections.reverse(lista);
array = lista.toArray(array);
```

En realidad es mejor trabajar con ArrayList si necesitamos hacer muchas manipulaciones como esta.

Si quieres algo más eficiente recomiendo algo como:

```
int inicio = 0;
int fin = array.length-1;
while(inicio < fin) {
   Integer temp = array[inicio];
   array[inicio] = array[fin];
   array[fin] = temp;
   inicio++;
   fin--;
}
```

Más mantenible tal vez, pero un poco menos claro con for:

```
for(int inicio= 0, fin = array.length-1; inicio < fin; inicio++,fin--) {
   Integer temp = array[inicio];
   array[inicio] = array[fin];
   array[fin] = temp;
}
```

Tu solución de pila también es posible pero menos eficiente:

```
LinkedList<Integer> reversa = new LinkedList<>();
for (Integer item : array) {
   reversa.addFirst(item);
}
array = reversa.toArray(array);
```

Aquí tu LinkedList actúa como pila.